# Spring HandlerInterceptor with apache tiles not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I want to intercept every request in spring MVC to perform some task. I configured HandlerInterceptor for this but because of some reason it's not working.

```
public class TestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter  {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Pre-handle");

        return false;
    }

}
```

Spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd ">


    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.abc.controller.TestInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

I referred this link to implement this :- 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/

Tried few more approaches but it's not working. 
Do I need to do something else because I am using tiles.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with tiles, problem is with your `TestInterceptor` itself ,
in preHandle() you are returning false , which should be true.

According to spring docs , preHandle() returns true if the execution chain should proceed with the next interceptor or the handler itself. Else, DispatcherServlet assumes that this interceptor has already dealt with the response itself.

So because your preHandle() is returning false your request is not proceeding further.

Comment: Control is not even coming in this method. I am trying to debug and it's not coming here. There is something wrong in configuring this interceptor that I am unable to identify .